# Google Admob on IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, admob

I want to put google ads after few list items in the list. So that I can have multiple ads in the list when I scroll down. Can any one help me out with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the plugin:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-admob
```

and include the script in your index.html:

```
<script src="lib/angular-admob/angular-admob.js"></script>
```

The next is similar to cordova app, wrapped inside angular functionality:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['admobModule']);

app.run(['admobSvc', function (admobSvc) {
  admobSvcProvider.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",  // Required
    interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",  // Optional
  });

  admobSvc.createBannerView();
  // You could also call admobSvc.createBannerView(options);


  // Handle events:
  $rootScope.$on(admobSvc.events.onAdOpened, function onAdOpened(evt, e) {
    console.log('adOpened: type of ad:' + e.adType);
  });
}]);
```

Here you can find complete instructions: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already implemented google ads on the bottom of the app. I want to put ads in the list after every sixth element. Could you please help me with that?